# Python Exception isn't printing entire exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
js = {'value': {'boot': {'delay': 0} } }
```

When I run the following command

```
print(js['value']['boot']['delay'])
```

I get `0` which is the behavior I expect to get.

When I run the following

```
print(js['value']['booooot']['delay'])
```

I get `KeyError: 'booooot'` which is also expected.

However, when I wrap all of this into a try/except and print the exception, I don't get the error as I expected.

```
def myfunc(js):
    try:
        js['value']['booooot']['delay']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I just get the following at the console `'booooot'`

Shouldn't I get `KeyError: 'booooot'` as I did when I ran the print outside of a try/except block?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
def func(js):
    try:
        print(js['value']['boooot']['delay'])
    except:
        print("Error Information: " + str(sys.exc_info()))

js = {'value': {'boot': {'delay': 0} } }
func(js)
```

The command `sys.exc_info()` will return the exception information as a tuple, with index `0` being the error type and index `1` with the error itself.
The code above prints out

```
Error Information: (<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('boooot'), <traceback object at 0x01867558>)
```

Thanks for asking!  Hope this helps.